# to disable a label of repeater on some condition in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Markup**

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <asp:Label ID="label12" runat="server" Text="Editor"></asp:Label>
            </th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label label12 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label12");
        Label activeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEditor");
        string s = activeLabel.Text;
        if (s != "Sao Palo")
        {
            activeLabel.Visible = true;
            label12.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {                    
            activeLabel.Visible = false;
            label12.Visible = false;   
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` at:

```
label12.visible=true;
```

Comment: Can you also show you ASP.NET code?

Comment: where did u get the null reference exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't that type casting fail if it was in line label12.visible = true ?

Comment: @Mino: No. `(Label)null` is okay.

Comment: it's a repeater and when I run the code it is giving null reference exception at label12.visible=true;

Comment: You should really work on your variable names, `lblHeadEditor` instead of `label12` for example.

Comment: okay I will work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This label is in the header, that's why it cannot be found in the repeater-items.
So change `e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)` to `e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header`.

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        Label label12 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label12");
        // ...
    }
}
```

But since the other label is not in the hader but in in an item you need a different approach.  You can also get the header-label via `Repeater.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("label12");`.

So this should work:

```
protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label label12 = (Label)((Repeater)sender).Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("label12");;
        Label activeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEditor");
        string s = activeLabel.Text;
        if (s != "Sao Palo")
        {
            activeLabel.Visible = true;
            label12.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {                    
            activeLabel.Visible = false;
            label12.Visible = false;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably still fail because `activeLabel` is not defined in `HeaderTemplate`

Comment: if I change like this it is giving same exception at string s = activeLabel.Text;

Comment: but it is giving Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.

Comment: @user3789358: i've forgotten to cast it to `Label`, corrected.

Comment: help me  Tim Schmelter. I am struck. I did't get it.

Comment: @user3789358: i have already edited my answer as mentioned above. If you don't see what i've changed look at the revision history(click `edited n mins ago` below my answer, added content is green): http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24489344/revisions